# How to get unmask value in MVC controller

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using jquery.inputmask.js in my project as

```
 $("#SSN").inputmask({
            "mask": "999-99-9999", 'autoUnmask': true,
            onUnMask: function (value) {
                return value.replace('-', '');
            }

        });
```

It works fine when displaying. But when i post this model and read the values in controller, it is still giving 999-99-9999 instead of 999999999.

I don't want to read each value and replace them as

```
Model.SSN.Replace('-','')
```

before saving. Please help.

Thanks!!!!

EDIT:

When i read  `$("#SSN").val()` in jquery it is returning 999999999 format, but not in controller(c#).

Comment: Besides `autoUnmask`, have you tried `removeMaskOnSubmit:true`?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this before submitting your form:

```
$("#SSN").inputmask('remove');
```

The above code will remove the mask from the element given with element id, in this case '#SSN'.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @BobKruithof it is just needed to be added above code to onclick of the submit button. .inputmask('remove') will remove related mask from the element given with element id which is "#SSN" in this case.

Answer (score -1):

As showed in [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.inputmask#unmaskedvalue)

You can use `$().inputmask("unmaskedvalue");`
Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include most essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also elaborate the answer..Please check [answer]