# Get textbox value having maskedextender using jquery Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get the value of a textbox which is having maskedextender(AjaxControlToolkit) using JQUERY.

I am unable to get the value. I am getting "___" (maskedvalue) but not typed value.

My code is like this:

```
<asp:TextBox Width="20%" ID="txtP1DayTimeNumber1" runat="server" MaxLength="3" />
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="meDayTimeNumber1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtP1DayTimeNumber1"  Mask="999" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false">
</ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
```

jquery code:

```
$("#txtP1DayTimeNumber1").val()
```

which is giving `"___"`.

Please help me in this.

Comment: have you tried .cleanVal()  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637938/how-to-get-unmask-value-in-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

```
                                    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AjaxForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicData_JIM.AjaxForm" %>

                                    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
                                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                    <head runat="server">
                                        <title></title>

                                        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                                        <script type="text/javascript">

                                            function getvalue() {
                                                var result = $("#txtP1DayTimeNumber1").val();
                                                result = result.replace("___", "")
                                                alert(result);
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        </script>

                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                        <form id="form1" runat="server">
                                        <div>
                                            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
                                            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                                            <input type="button" id="btnclick" runat="server" value="Click" name="Click" title="Click"
                                                onclick="return getvalue();">
                                            <asp:TextBox Width="20%" ID="txtP1DayTimeNumber1" runat="server" MaxLength="3" />
                                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meDayTimeNumber1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtP1DayTimeNumber1"
                                                Mask="999" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false">
                                            </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </body>
                                    </html>
```